# Recorded Web Performance Test in VS 2015 shows error

Tags: visual-studio, testing, visual-studio-2015, load-testing

I'm new to load testing using VS 2015. Right now, I'm working on load testing for a web project which will need recorded web performance tests for each interaction that users would typically do with our application.

I recorded a web performance test for the simple logging-in of user in the website. After clicking the stop button in browser, the web performance test was generated in the VS 2015 but with an error.

Although I successfully logged in during the recorded web performance test, I was wondering if should I be worried with the error displayed and would affect the load testing which I will be using the recorded web performance test for.

[Error message: 1 primary requests, 1 dependant requests and 0  conditional rules failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEeRx.png)

When the error message is clicked, the following details would show up:

- Access denied (authentication_failed)
- 404 - File or Directory not found SERVER ERROR

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After the stop button on the browser is pressed, Visual Studio runs the test once to help it find dynamic data, etc. Commonly this execution of the test fails, so do not worry about this failure.

You should then expect to run the test yourself a number of times, to make it work properly. Before each execution you may need to make changes, for example:

- for data driving
- for adding credentials
- for adding verification rules
- to sort out dynamic data that Visual Studio has not detected, this will probably include adding extraction rules